# Android TV how to show a numeric keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-tv

I need to show only the numbers on the keyboard.

I have tried

***android:inputType="numberPassword"***

***editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);***

But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

- android:inputType="number"

or by code

- editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);